# .push() on Float32Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't use .push() on a Float32Array, I get an error, so I tried to add it like this :

```
myarray = new Float32Array() ;
myarray.push = function()
{
    for( var i in arguments )
    {
        this[this.length] = arguments[i] ;
    }
} ;
```

But it does not work. I do not get errors, but my array's values are all 0.
Why ?

Comment: Float32Arrays are typed arrays and as such just have a fixed length. You just can't modify them on the fly.

Comment: @Sirko Took me three minutes of faffing around in the browser console for me to figure that out XD

Comment: @Sirko Make that an answer and link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array#Element_size The only methods on it are `get` and `set`

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you expect to do with your array.

Comment: I see, so since I can't change its length, I edited and tried myarray = new Float32Array(12); and used a variable myarray_length since its real length would always be 12, but I still get 0. I can't change its values neither after creation ?

Comment: @Diego Works just fine: `var a = new Float32Array( 2 ); console.log( JSON.stringify( a ) ); a[0] = 3; console.log( JSON.stringify( a ) );`

Comment: @Pointy That is the array I use for WebGL, usual line is gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([(coordinates)]) , gl.STATIC_DRAW ); , instead of creating a new Float32Array at each call, I want to have only one Float32Array I define before the function and just change its values in the function, to avoid creating garbage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically a [`Float32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Float32Array) is just a view over an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer) object (as are all typed arrays in JS). This `ArrayBuffer` has a fixed length, which in turn the `Float32Array` inherits.

So to conclude: You just can not change the size of your `Float32Array` on the fly. The only possibility would be as this:

1. Create a new array with the length of the old array + 1
2. Copy all items of the old array over to the new array.
3. Insert the new item as the last item in the new array.
4. Replace all instances of the old array with the new array.

If you want to add multiple values on multiple occasions, I strongly advise against this. This completely negates any performance advantage you might gain from using typed arrays!

Answer (score 5):

Typed arrays like Float32Array is designed as lower level approach which make more sense if you are familiar with dynamic memory allocation (like in C).

Here we have **memory allocated** (the underlying ArrayBuffer) and **memory used** (assigned items in typed array), which doesn't have to be the same thing in raw memory.

You can push to typed arrays like this:

```
(myarray = new Float32Array(myarray.length+1)).set([...myarray, appendix])
```

where `appendix` is the new item you want to push. It is not just ugly, but also very ineffective: you should predict how much the array would grow and allocate more extra space instead of just `+1` (and remember how much space is left).

To make it memory effective, you could share one underlying ArrayBuffer (see examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set)), just remember that every item in Float32Array takes 4 bytes in ArrayBuffer.

If you dont want to bother with this and you just want to push anytime, just stay with the old generic Array.

Answer (score 2):

Typed arrays are part of an [involved system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) for dealing with raw "machine-level" data. If you just want a simple array of 32-bit floating point numbers, you can create it with a fixed length and use it *somewhat* like a normal array:

```
var f32 = new Float32Array(10);
f32[0] = 100;
alert(f32[0]); // 100
```

Answer (score 1):

(myarray = new Float32Array(myarray.length+1)).set([...myarray, appendix])

> not working, too complicated...

Simply used :

```
myarray = new Float32Array([...myarray, 14, 1]);
```

or you can do :

```
myarray = new Float32Array([5, 1, 2]) ;
myarray.push = function()
{
    myarray = new Float32Array([...myarray, ...arguments]);
};

myarray.push(5, 8);
```

Comment: This is pretty slick

Comment: De structuring on a typed Array? also.. doesn't  create alot of garbage(the size of array) on every push?